# Efficient ways of calculating affinity only for local neighbourhood in a large graph

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, affinity

I am relatively new to python and numpy and am trying to cluster a dense matrix with floating point numbers and having dimensions of 256x256 using spectral clustering. Since the affinity matrix will be of size 65536x65536, a full affinity matrix cannot be computed (due to memory limitations). As such, I am currently calculating the affinity between a given matrix entry and its 5x5 local neighbourhood, and build a sparse graph (in 3-tuple representation).

To do so, I am using for loops (basically, a sliding widow approach) which I think is not the most efficient way of doing so.

```
import numpy as np

def getAffinity(f1, f2):
    return np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(np.absolute(f1 - f2))/ 2.1)

G = np.arange(256*256).reshape((256,256))
dim1 = 256 # Dimension 1 of matrix
dim2 = 256 # Dimension 1 of matrix
values = np.zeros(1623076, dtype=np.float32) # To hold affinities
rows = np.zeros(1623076, dtype=np.int32) # To hold row index
cols = np.zeros(1623076, dtype=np.int32) # To hold column index
index = 0 # To hold column index

for i in range(dim1):
    for j in range(dim2):
        current = G[i, j]
        for k in range(np.maximum(0, i-2), np.minimum(dim1 , i+3)): # traverse rows
            for l in range(np.maximum(0, j-2), np.minimum(dim2 , j+3)): # traverse columns
                rows[index] = i*d1 + j
                cols[index] = k*d1 + l
                values[index] = getAffinity(current, G[k, l])
                index += 1
```

I was wondering whether there are any other efficient ways of achieving the same goal.

Comment: `cols = rows` looks like a bug to me. (You are creating an alias, not a new object.)

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks. It seems to work though. However, I edited the code a little.
Any thoughts on a more efficient method to do this?

Comment: It doesn't crash, but it gives wrong results. Also, `linalg.norm` doesn't seem very useful since you are passing a non negative scalar on which norm is a nop.

Comment: I will double check my results then. As for the norm calculation, these are not the actual values that I'm using. The actual values are a multi-dimensional vector (i.e. The actual G is an ndarray with 3 dimensions). The code was only to demonstrate what I wanted to achieve and I thought extending a possible solution  to accommodate third dimension would be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sparse matrix approach. It is >800x faster than the loopy code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from time import perf_counter as pc

T = []
T.append(pc())
def getAffinity(f1, f2):
    return np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(np.absolute(f1 - f2))/ 2.1)

G = 2*np.arange(256*256).reshape((256,256))
dim1 = 256 # Dimension 1 of matrix
dim2 = 256 # Dimension 1 of matrix
values = np.zeros(1623076, dtype=np.float32) # To hold affinities
rows = np.zeros(1623076, dtype=np.int32) # To hold row index
cols = np.zeros(1623076, dtype=np.int32) # To hold column index
index = 0 # To hold column index

for i in range(dim1):
    for j in range(dim2):
        current = G[i, j]
        for k in range(np.maximum(0, i-2), np.minimum(dim1 , i+3)): # traverse rows
            for l in range(np.maximum(0, j-2), np.minimum(dim2 , j+3)): # traverse columns
                rows[index] = i*dim1 + j
                cols[index] = k*dim1 + l
                values[index] = getAffinity(current, G[k, l])
                index += 1

T.append(pc())

affs_OP = sparse.coo_matrix((values,(rows,cols))).tocsr()

import scipy.sparse as sp

def getAffinity(f1, f2): # similar to @PaulPanzer, I don't think OP is right
    return np.exp(-np.abs(f1 - f2)/ 2.1)


def affinity_block(dim = 256, dist = 2):
    i = np.arange(-dist, dist+1)
    init_block = sp.dia_matrix((np.ones((i.size, dim)), i), (dim, dim))
    out = sp.kron(init_block, init_block).tocoo()
    out.data = getAffinity(Gf[out.row], Gf[out.col])
    return out

T.append(pc())

Gf = G.ravel()
offsets = np.concatenate((np.mgrid[1:3,-2:3].reshape(2,-1).T,np.mgrid[:1,1:3].reshape(2,-1).T), axis=0)
def make_diag(yo,xo):
    o = 256*yo+xo
    diag = np.exp(-np.abs(Gf[o:]-Gf[:-o])/2.1)
    if xo>0:
        diag[:xo-256].reshape(-1,256)[:,-xo:] = 0
    elif xo<0:
        diag[:xo].reshape(-1,256)[:,:-xo] = 0
        diag[xo:] = 0
    return diag
diags = [make_diag(*o) for o in offsets]
offsets = np.sum(offsets*[256,1], axis=1)
affs_pp = sparse.diags([*diags,[np.ones(256*256)],*diags],np.concatenate([offsets,[0],-offsets]))

T.append(pc())

affs_df = affinity_block()

T.append(pc())

print("OP: {:.3f} s  convert OP to sparse matrix: {:.3f} s   pp {:.3f} s   df: {:.3f} s".format(*np.diff(T)))

diff = affs_pp-affs_OP
diff *= diff.sign()
md = diff.max()

print(f"max deviation pp-OP: {md}")
print(f"number of different entries pp-df: {(affs_pp-affs_df).nnz}")
```

Sample run:

```
OP: 23.392 s  convert OP to sparse matrix: 0.020 s   pp 0.025 s   df: 0.093 s
max deviation pp-OP: 2.0616356788405454e-08
number of different entries pp-df: 0
```

A bit of explanation, 1D first to keep it simple. Let's imagine an actually sliding window, so we can use time as an intuitive axis:

```
        space
  +-------------->       
  |           
t |    xo...     x: window center
i |    oxo..     o: window off center
m |    .oxo.     .: non window
e |    ..oxo
  |    ...ox
  v
```

time here actually is equivalent to space because we move with constant speed. We can now see that all the window points can be described as three diagonals. Offsets are 0, 1 and -1 but note that because the affinities are symmetric and the one for 0 is trivial, we need only calculate them for 1.

Now lets skip to 2D, the smallest example we can do is 3x3 window in 4x4 array. In row major this looks like.

```
xo..oo..........
oxo.ooo.........
.oxo.ooo........
..ox..oo........
oo..xo..oo......
ooo.oxo.ooo.....
.ooo.oxo.ooo....
..oo..ox..oo....
....oo..xo..oo..
....ooo.oxo.ooo.
.....ooo.oxo.ooo
......oo..ox..oo
........oo..xo..
........ooo.oxo.
.........ooo.oxo
..........oo..ox
```

The relevant offsets are (0,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1) or in row major 0x4+1 = 1, 1x4-1 = 3, 1x4+0 = 4, 1x4+1 = 5. Also note that most of these diagonals are not complete, the missing bits explained by row major wrapping around, i.e. at z = y,x x = 3 the right neighbor z+1 is not actually a right neighbor y,x+1 ; instead, because of line jump, it is y+1,0 The if-else clause in the code above blanks the right bits of each diagonal.

@DanielF's strategy is similar but takes advantage of the block structure evident in the figure.

```
xo.. oo.. .... ....
oxo. ooo. .... ....
.oxo .ooo .... ....
..ox ..oo .... ....

oo.. xo.. oo.. ....
ooo. oxo. ooo. ....
.ooo .oxo .ooo ....
..oo ..ox ..oo ....

.... oo.. xo.. oo..
.... ooo. oxo. ooo.
.... .ooo .oxo .ooo
.... ..oo ..ox ..oo

.... .... oo.. xo..
.... .... ooo. oxo.
.... .... .ooo .oxo
.... .... ..oo ..ox
```

Comment: Can't quite follow but I hink this is going in the same direction I was.  blocks of diagonal matrices?

Comment: @DanielF Yep. When you flatten the 256x256 array and use that to index the 256^2x256^2 table of (ordered) pairs of array elements then the set of pairs with the same (2D, directed) offset will form a (sub-) diagonal. (More precisely, since it is 2D a subset of a diagonal because you have to leave out the places where the offset wraps around because row-major jumps to the next row) Therefore a sliding window generates a bunch of diagonals. Is that where you were going?

Comment: Yeah, except I didn't realize that `scipy.sparse.kronsum` doesn't do what I expected (namely, the same thing as `kron` but with addition), which made my nice elegant solution a mess.

Comment: Thanks for code and I'm trying to figure out exactly what's being done (there are couple of new functions that I'm not familiar with).

Comment: @PaulPanzer Could you please explain what's going behind this code? I can't seems to get my head around how the offsets are used here, even after trying for an hour or so.

Comment: @RMTR Could you pls ask a bit more concrete? Let's start from my comment to Daniel F. Can you follow the general strategy? Perhaps try in 1D first. If you make a table of a sliding window (reference (center) point on y axis, actual window points on x axis) you get a broad diagonal, right? Because a diagonal are pairs of coordinates with a fixed offset x-y = const and a sliding shape is defined by having each of its points always at the same offset to some reference. Can you follow so far?

Comment: Sorry, what I specifically don't understand how the concept of offsets is used here. To be honest, I can't even figure out how you came up with those offset values. I was under the impression that these offsets are same as the ones that is mentioned in [numpy.diagonal](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html). But I feel I'm wrong as I can't seems to figure it out.

Comment: @RMTR I've tried to explain better, see updated post.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you very much for taking time to explain it. Now it's crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bit more elegant and extensible, albeit a bit (4x) slower, way to do the same thing as @PaulPanzer

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
from functools import reduce

def getAffinity(f1, f2): # similar to @PaulPanzer, I don't think OP is right
    return np.exp(-np.abs(f1 - f2)/ 2.1)

def affinity_block(G, dist = 2):
    Gf = G.ravel()
    i = np.arange(-dist, dist+1)
    init_blocks = [1]
    for dim in G.shape:
        init_blocks.append(sp.dia_matrix((np.ones((i.size, dim)), i), (dim, dim)))
    out = reduce(sp.kron, init_blocks).tocoo()
    out.data = getAffinity(Gf[out.row], Gf[out.col])
    return out
```

This allows non-square `G` matrices, and higher dimensions.

Comment: You probably want something like `out.data = getAffinity(Gf[out.row], Gf[out.col])` (In the example it doesn't show because Gf happpens to be 0,1,2,...) - Apart from that very nice, but not truly faster than mine (because 80% of the time mine takes is conversion to `csr` format which may be a daft idea anyway).

Comment: @PaulPanzer true, fixed.